# React does not render component to url's that uses dynamic routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to match the url path to perform dynamic routing, but the component is not being Rendered at the path. What am i doing wrong here?

btw the route to the CollectionsOverview component is working.

Shop Component.js :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/huBj1.jpg

```
onst ShopPage = ({ match }) => {
  console.log(`Shop Component ${match.path}`);
  return (
    <div className='shop-page'>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`/${match.path}`} component={CollectionsOverview} />
        <Route
          path={`/${match.path}/:collectionId`}
          component={CollectionPage}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShopPage;
```

---

Collection Component.js:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN89X.jpg

```
const CollectionPage = () => {
  console.log(`Collection Page`);
  return (
    <div className='collection-page'>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

Result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaoT4.jpg

Comment: Please don't use images as code samples. Just paste them inside here or in a jsfiddle. It makes it harder for people to help you if you don't

Comment: Thanks for the advice Mick,Updated the question with the code.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Put `/${match.path}/:collectionId` path before `/${match.path}` and remove `exact` from route.

Here is working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dynamic-routing-r714l

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const CollectionOverview = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>CollectionOverview</div> <br />
      <Link to="/collection/1">To Collection 1</Link> <br />
      <Link to="/collection/2">To Collection 2</Link> <br />
      <Link to="/collection/3">To Collection 3</Link> <br />
      <Link to="/collection/4">To Collection 4</Link> <br />
    </div>
  );
};

const CollectionPage = props => {
  return <div>CollectionPage for ID: {props.match.params.id}</div>;
};

const HomeComponent = () => {
  return <div>Home Component</div>;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Link to="/">To Home</Link>
        <br />
        <Link to="/collection">To Collection Overview</Link>
        <br />
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/collection/:id" component={CollectionPage} />
        <Route path="/collection" component={CollectionOverview} />
        <Route path="/" component={HomeComponent} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```